# Tree structure for rectangles

Tags: c++, user-interface, tree, rectangles

I want to know what particular tree algorithm is best for **GUI** system, as for `N x (rectangles within rectangle)`

So far, the structure of my implementation is described by the image below.

### A simple diagram of the whole structure:

[image: solid base class structure]

`swcObject` is the base class of all the widgets i.e `buttons, textboxes, labels, etc...`

Each of w/c can hold another of their same kind and I call it as their *components*. For example, I would call the `scrollbar`'s three buttons (i.e up/left, down/right, and thumb) as **components**, and for the `document` with scrollbars (vertical and horizontal) as **components** while the object that is addable (*can contain buttons, label, textboxes, texts or can contain another document again*) is **contents**.

### Source code for base class:

```
class swcObject :
    public swcRectangle
{
public:

    swcObject();

protected:

    addComponent(swcObject *component);

private:

    std::vector<swcObject*> components;

};
```

### And some derived class from the solid concept of base class

```
class swcDocument :
    public swcObject
{
public:

    typedef std::shared_ptr<swcObject> spObject;

    swcDocument();

    addContent(const spObject& object);

protected:

    std::vector<spObject> vspContents;

};
```

A simple diagram of what I'm trying to work on now but can't still achieve a perfect example.

[image: derived class with another components]

The problem in my current implementation is that, if I would select a particular object, let's say e.g a button overlapped by another button within a document(I called the rectangle with scrollbars as `document`), it would have select the document also. I try to reverse iterate it and when the mouse button has been pressed for the first time, it will lock any mouse click events until the mouse button is released again. But, what if I will create another class that will hold another **contents** again, I will re-implement again the code and also this causes me some other issues on the **component** side. What could be the best solution for the entire iteration over the rectangle with recursion?

**Update**

> Why does your library have these issues?

-Because I only started coding it about 4months. And I'm not a prodigy to answer all the mathematical problems I will be encounter.

> In what ways it is unique?

-IDK, haven't seen any GUI (or related) code before.

> Can you show how it all happens in code?

### Layer1

```
class swcObject
{
    std::vector<swcObject*> components;
};

void swcObject::update()
{
    for (auto &i : components)
    {
        //fetch inputs
        i->update();
    }
}
```

### Layer2

```
class swcDocument
{
    std::vector<spObject> contents;
};

void swcDocument::update()
{
    for (auto &i : boost::adaptors::reverse(contents))
    {
        //fetch inputs
        i->update();
    }
}
```

### Layer3

```
class swcApplication
{
    std::vector<spObject> contents;
};

void swcApplication::execute()
{
    for (auto &i : boost::adaptors::reverse(contents))
    {
        //fetch inputs
        i->update();
    }
}
```

I reverse iterate it because I drew(paint) each rectangle as in *Painter's algorithm*

Comment: You have revealed approximately nothing about the structure of your code. If it's a GUI library, it's pretty safe to assume it has rectangles within rectangles, and rectangles having rectangles as children. Why does your library have these issues? In what ways it is unique? Can you show how it all happens in code? Pseudocode will do as long as it can be followed.

Comment: @n.m. I don't know if I answered you're question really correct but I think that helps. See updated post.

Comment: How does the order of iteration matter?

Comment: @n.m. Which will be prioritized first on occurrences of events?

Comment: You have a reasonable recursion/iteration structure, though why you reverse the iteration order is unclear. But there's only update code. You didn't show how e.g. mouse events are handled.

Comment: @n.m. I'm sorry I didn't show the whole thing thinking it would mess up the post. I will add it lately. The reason I reverse iterate is because I drew(or paint) them in normal order. As what painter's algorithm does. Mouse event's and others are fetches on the commented region in the loop.

Comment: "Which will be prioritized first" — what do you mean? If you need them prioritized according to e.g. z-order, then keep them sorted in z-order. Why rely on the order of creation? Z can change.

Comment: @n.m. I prefer the *Painter's algorithm* because I have researched about it and it is memory efficient though it's hard to implement. I just really need a decent structure for handling all of the events occurred and w/c are to be prioritized first.

Comment: Ah ok, you paint and handle events in the opposite order. Sounds reasonable

Comment: @n.m. Yeah. Do you know any links that has a source code for it related to GUI making? I think my question is too broad and I might not get any answers from this. I try Googling other GUI library but I can't see the very core of it.

Comment: I would study the InterViews toolkit source. It's the archetypal native C++ GUI library. Start here: http://www.ivtools.org/ivtools/ivtools-layers.html